# After uncheking out files in clearcase, cc_cset still show that file in active elements?

Tags: version-control, clearcase

I want to publish some component in my clearcase view. I initially checked out some file. Then I unchecked out it. And tried to publish a component. But it says, component has active elements in changeset.

If I try to uncheckout again, it says, no checked out file, but cc_cset shows the file as checkedc out.

What to do?

Comment: Are we talking about ClearCase or RTC? (IBM Rational Team Concert). If ClearCase, what version (7.x? 8.x ClearTeam? CCRC?) What OS?

Comment: We are using clearcase.

Comment: Ok. What version of ClearCase on what OS?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible (assuming ClearCase) that the file is checked out in a different view.

A version tree on that element should be able to show you which view.